# Send list of objects which contain other custom objects from one activity to another

Tags: android, android-activity, parcelable, serializable

This is my class whose list I want to send to another activity.

```
public class PostComments {

    public User from;

    public String message;

    public String createdTime;

    public String like_count;

    public Boolean user_likes;
}
```

This is User class whose object is used in PostComments class.

```
public class User extends BaseEntity{
    public String photoUrl;
}
```

And this is BaseEntity Class

```
public class BaseEntity {
    public String Id;

    public String Name;
}
```

How can I send this object from one activity to another?

```
PostComments[] myData = ClickedPost.comments.data;
Intent PostCommentsActivity = new Intent(getActivity() , PostCommentsActivity.class);
getActivity().startActivity(PostCommentsActivity);
```

Above is the code to open PostCommentsActivity and I want to send myData object to the PostCommentsActivity.

I have searched alot about this problem but every question and tutorial explain that only for a class which contains simple string, int or boolean variables.

Comment: Why do you want to send that much data over?  Why not just send an ID of an object and then retrieve/construct that object at the destination?

Comment: All else failed, you can always serialise the object and deserialise at the destination.

Comment: I just want to show this array of my comments on second activity by any means. Can you provide some link that how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try:

```
ArrayList<PostComments> comments = new ArrayList<MainActivity.PostComments>();
comments.add(...) //Add your list data here
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity() , PostCommentsActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("list_comments", comments);
getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

And edit your PostComments Class to:

```
public class PostComments implements Serializable {

        public String message;

        public String createdTime;

        public String like_count;

        public Boolean user_likes;
    }
```

In PostCommentsActivity, get bundle to get list comments.

Comment: PostComments[] myData = ClickedPost.comments.data;

Comment: I don't have arraylist, its a simple array coming from server. How can I change it to ArrayList<PostComments>?

Comment: This may not work.  All of the OP's classes have to be Serialisable for this to work

Comment: @Yawar if you have to ask this question, then I suggest you start by learning java

Comment: Can't you provide a tutorial on this. I have completed whole application and now I just need this for my last feature?

Comment: @AleksG: If you send single object, you must implement Serialisable .

Comment: @Yawar: you can use for loop to add single object to arraylist, or use AddAll to add whole array.

Comment: @TruongPhuQuoc When you are sending a list or array of objects, each one of them must be serialisable - I know this, but you need to include this into your answer.

Comment: @AleksG: Sorry, i'm wrong. Thank you very much. I'm updating my answer

Comment: My class also has a property of type User, will it send that too ?